# Air compressor air filter and oil change

Tags: tools, air-filter, lubrication

My Makita MAC2400 has been serving great almost a decade now. Recently I started wondering about the volume of air it has intaken over the year and that it all went through the air filter, which I have never changed. So I opened the filter housing and it didn't look too terrible:

[image]

Is it necessary to replace this filter occasionally and does mine look overdue? Here is the compressor:

[image]

Also, how frequently should the oil be changed? Unlike most small compressors, this one is lubed for quieter operation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Compressors do need to have the oil changed usually based on hours of operation. Since it has been 10 years I would change the oil. The filter is hard to see in the photo. I usually blow air on my filters to clean them if working in dusty areas, Sawdust blows out easily dirt tends to build up. Shine a light in the filter can you see the light on the other side? If no time to replace. Maybe you will get another 10 years but I would change the oil a bit more often.